# How can I get an existing JMS queue?

Tags: java, jms, jndi, ibm-mq

I feel like this is probably a pretty simple question, but this is my first foray into JMS, so I am a little unsure.

I am trying to write to an existing JMS queue (and then read from another queue), for which I know the queue name, host, queue manager, and channel.  How do I get a reference to this queue in the form of a `javax.jms.Destination` object?

All of the examples I have found involve calling `javax.jms.Session.createQueue(String)`, but since this queue already exists, I don't want to create another one, right?  Or am I misunderstanding what is going on?

If it matters, I am using the com.ibm.msg.client.jms driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the container in which your application runs will bind the `Queue` in its naming service. An application in the container can look it up with JNDI and use it.

Comment: Thanks!  Is it possible to access the queue from a standalone java program?  Eventually, I will be using the Queue from a Java EE application, but right now I'm trying to just experiment get more familiar with JMS.  If it isn't possible to do this, I can probably skip this step, but I would like to have some code that interacts with the Queue without all the other complexity in my application.

Comment: Usually it is possible to do this from a standalone application, but the details depend a lot on the JMS provider you are using. For example, many app servers provide a JNDI provider and JMS driver that you can use in an application outside the app server itself to establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

To add erickson's answer above:

**This is an example of getting and browsing a JMS Queue:**  *(using javax.jms-api 2.x)*

```
 // Set up the connection to the queue:
 Properties env = new Properties();
 env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://<host>:<port>");
 Context namingContext = new InitialContext(env);
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
 JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext("jms_user", "pwd");

 // Get the JMS Queue:
 Queue queue = (Queue) namingContext.lookup("jms/queue/exampleQueue");
 // Create the JMS Browser:
 QueueBrowser browser = context.createBrowser(queue);
 // Browse the messages:
 Enumeration<Message> e = browser.getEnumeration();
 while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
     Message message = (Message) e.nextElement();
     log.debug(message.getBody(String.class) + " with priority: " + message.getJMSPriority());
 }
...
```

Make sure you use these Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```